# How to import images in django models from csv/excel?

Tags: python, django, excel, csv, django-file-upload

This is my model.

```
class Product(models.Model)
    id = models.AutoField(max_length=10,  primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='product_images', blank=True)
```

I know how to import data from csv in django model. But I also have image field here.

Can I upload files to models from the method of adding data to models from csv? How?

I am using this method for importing them: http://mitchfournier.com/2011/10/11/how-to-import-a-csv-or-tsv-file-into-a-django-model/

I have images stored in a folder in my system.

Comment: How can we answer, given that you haven't told us anything about what the CSVs contain or how you're importing them?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You would have given the answer if you knew how to import images into models. I don't know how to import images, then how can I tell you that how I am importing them? This is the question isn't it?

Comment: No. What is the "image" that is in your CSV? A filename? A URL? A base-64 encoded data string? You already have CSVs and code to import the data, which you should show.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Again, that is the question, how should I put it? You are free to share any of the way you think is better to import images in models.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just did a test run in other project for doing the same thing, so I don't have the code for this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Right now I have images in a folder.

Comment: So what does that have to do with a CSV then?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because I am importing this Product data. CSV is an easy way to import the data in bulk.

Answer (score 2):

[FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) is just a reference to a file. It does not put a file into the database as is sometimes mistakenly believed.

Assuming that you have already got the code written for reading through the CSV and fetching the location of the file. Then all you need to do is to follow the example given in [FileField.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField)

> This method takes a filename and file contents and passes them to the
>   storage class for the field, then associates the stored file with the
>   model field. If you want to manually associate file data with
>   FileField instances on your model, the save() method is used to
>   persist that file data.
>
> Takes two required arguments: name which is the name of the file, and
>   content which is an object containing the file’s contents.

Something like this:

```
p = Product()
p.image.save('name from csv',open('path from csv'))
```

Comment: This is helpful. I will implement and if it works I will select the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by saving the name of the image in the csv and just uploading the name in the field like this:

```
...
product.image = "product_images" + namefromcsv
```

then I uploaded all the images in the media folder inside `product_images` .

And it worked very well.

I tried uploading the image with product.image.save() option with `File` class but it didn't work for me.